# How to make a asynchronous call in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service which is exposed on http. After receiving the request the service validates it against its schema. Now if a validation fails, the service should send back client an error response and should also send that error message to a queue.

```
<validate [source="xpath"]>
   <property name="validation-feature-id" value="true|false"/>*
   <schema key="string"/>+
   <on-fail>
      mediator+
   </on-fail>
</validate>
```

**Problem:**

I am making a custom message in "Validate" mediator "on-fail" sequence. I am sending back that message by using "Response" mediator. After sending back the response I want to send this same error message to a jms queue. But the problem is that after "Respond" mediator, no mediator works and if I put "Call" mediator" before the "Respond" mediator, only message is sent to queue, no response is sent back to client.

**Things to achieve:**
To summarize, I need to do following two things in a validate mediator fault sequence.

- Send Back the Response to client.
- Send the response to a queue.

how can I achieve that or is there any alternative approach to achieve this task?

Comment: One thing to add that WSO2 does not allow us to put any mediator after "send" mediator.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

> I am making a custom message in "Validate" mediator "on-fail" sequence

I assume you are using payloadFactory. So , once you have built you're custom message , you can use the < clone > mediator to send the message to 2 destinations like so :

```
<clone>
    <target> 
        <sequence>
            <respond/>
        </sequence>
    </target>

    <target>
        <sequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri=""/> <!-- Specify the JMS connection URL here -->
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</clone>
```

Hope that works for you!